# Django: Combining search view with Pagination

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-pagination

In a Django CBV (ListView), after submitting a form using GET method, with `filter_1` and `filter_2` fields, the resulting URL I get is something like:

`http://example.com/order/advanced-search?filter_1=foo&filter_2=bar`

Everything is ok.
However, I'd like to use pagination, proving to my template a URL like:

`http://example.com/order/advanced-search?page=2&filter_1=foo&filter_2=bar`

Let's say I could override this method for this purpose:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['my_form_values'] = self.request.GET
```

Now, how can I use `my_form_values` in my pagination template to display the right URLs?

For now, here is my (simplified) pagination template code:

```
{% for num in page_obj.page_range %}
    {% if page_obj.number == num %}
        <li class="page-item active">
            <span class="page-link">{{ num }}</span>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The problem with `?page={{num}}` is that you've lost the rest of the filters (e.g. `filter_1=foo`). [Here's a template tag](https://gist.github.com/etchalon/4493752) that might be useful. I found it by searching *django querydict template tag*, I'm sure I've seen others in the past as well.

Comment: @Alasdair `href="?page={{ num }}&{% qs_alter request.GET -page %}"` is almost working. The only issue is that `page` parameter is not removed and is stacked. In the end, I got something like: `?page=3&page=4&filter_1=foo&filter_2=bar`

Comment: replacing `k, v = arg.split("-", 2)` (makes no sense because the key would be empty) with `_, k = arg.split("-", 2)` works ... I'm not sure I understood how to use this template tag actually.

Comment: From the [examples](https://gist.github.com/etchalon/4493752#file-gistfile1-py-L42), I think you want `?{% qs_alter request.GET page=num %}`, but if that doesn't work, I'm afraid I can't help you debug it because I haven't used that tag before. You might find it easier to search for a similar tag - I only included it as an example of the type of thing I've seen before.

Comment: Thanks it works as expected with  `{% qs_alter request.GET page=num %}`. Please consider writing an answer so that I accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def param_replace(context, **kwargs):
    d =context['request'].GET.copy()
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        d[k] = v
    for k in [k for k,v in d.items() if not v]:
        del d[k]
    return d.urlencode()
```

and then the pagination in template

```
<ul class="pagination">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                 href="?{% param_replace page=1 %}">{% trans 'first' %}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                 href="?{% param_replace page=page_obj.previous_page_number %}">{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link"
                                    href="?{{ page_obj.number }}">{{ page_obj.number }}</a>
    </li>
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                 href="?{% param_replace page=page_obj.next_page_number %}">{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                 href="?{% param_replace page=page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}">{% trans 'last' %}</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```